# Add DeletionPolicy to Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I need to add a `DeletionPolicy` to my functions created with the serverless framework. [Override AWS CloudFormation Resource](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources#override-aws-cloudformation-resource) suggests that I should be able to do something like the following, but it doesn't work:

```
functions:
  my-function:
    name: my-function
    handler: index.handler

resources:
  extensions:
    MyDashFunctionLambdaFunction:
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out we were on a rather old version of serverless. This was added in version 1.65.0.